# Filter rows in datagridview in C#.net windows application

Tags: datagridview

How to filter rows in datagridview C#.net windows application , as we write text in the textbox at runtime the filtered rows should appear in the datgridview

Answer (score 1):

This did work for me:

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
bs.Filter = sColumnaDoPrzeszukania + " like '%" + textBox1.Text + "%'";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
```

The whole question is here:
[How to filter a datagridview by a textbox after loading an excel file into it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497460/how-to-filter-a-datagridview-by-a-textbox-after-loading-an-excel-file-into-it)

Answer (score 0):

On your textbox, create a method for the "TextChanged" event that calls your query method.  Similar to this:

```
private void btnFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetData();
}
```

GetData is your method that retrieves data from your database.

Comment: If you retrieves data from database, at every filtering you probably lose the changes made to the datagridview.
it's better to use a built-in filtering function and not to reload the datasource at every filtering event (it's also more ligth for the application).